# Notepad++ keeps hijacking my custom icons

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, icons

**Note:**
Windows 10 machine, 64-bit.

I'm using FileTypesMan, and I successfully change the icons of certain extensions:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

So far, so good. But when I double click a file, I choose Notepad++ as the default program to open the file:

[image]

And then things go wrong. Notepad++ hijacks the icon. All `*.c` files now get displayed with the Notepad++ icon.

How can I prevent Notepad++ from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is NOT using `FileTypesMan`, but editing the registry itself. After long trial and error, I found a registry setup that allows me to assign custom icons to filetypes.

### Preparations

**1. Registry permissions**
Open the Windos registry, and give yourself enough "permissions" for the folders `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. I'm not sure myself what are the minimum settings for the whole procedure to succeed. You've got to play a bit with the settings. Anytime you get an error message in the coming procedure, go back to this step and increase your registry permissions.

**2. Make some custom icons**
Make some custom icons, for example in the folder `C:\ICONS\`. I use the following website https://iconverticons.com/online/ to convert 256x256 png-files into ico-files.

**3. Install Notepad++**
Just get Notepad++. Nothing special here.

**4. Open a terminal with admin rights**
Type `cmd` in the windows search bar. Right click on the CMD-icon that appears and choose "Run as administrator" in the popup window.

### Registry hacking

*Disclaimer: changing your registry can potentially cause damage to your Windows installation. I have written down the procedure below with best intentions, but I deny any responsibility in case something goes wrong.*
*Note: I DON'T recommend to use this procedure for `.bat` files. This is a very important file-type for Windows. So I don't know what would happen if you delete its standard registry keys.*

The procedure below describes how to assign a custom icon - which you created in `C:\ICONS\abcfile.ico` - to all `*.abc` files.

**1. Registry hacking, part one**
The first registry key you should add is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc`. In case this key already exists, you might want to delete it. Use the following command to delete the key and all its subkeys:

```
> REG DELETE HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc /f
```

The following figure shows how we will (re)build this registry key and all its subkeys:

[image]

You can do it manually or run the following commands:

```
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc /ve /t REG_SZ /d "abc_auto_file"
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc /v BrowserFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc /v EditFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc /v PerceivedType /t REG_SZ /d "text"
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc\DefaultIcon /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\ICONS\abcfile.ico,0"
```

**2. Registry hacking, part two**
The second registry key you should add is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file`. In case this key already exists, you might want to delete it. Use the following command to delete the key and all its subkeys:

```
> REG DELETE HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file /f
```

The following figure shows how we will (re)build this registry key and all its subkeys:

[image]

You can do it manually or run the following commands:

```
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file\DefaultIcon /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\ICONS\abcfile.ico"
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file\shell /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file\shell\edit /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file\shell\edit\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\" \"^%1\""
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file\shell\open /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abc_auto_file\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\" \"^%1\""
```

**3. Registry hacking, part three**
The second registry key you should add is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc`. In case this key already exists, you might want to delete it. Use the following command to delete the key and all its subkeys:

```
> REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc /f
```

The following figure shows how we will (re)build this registry key and all its subkeys:

[image]

You can do it manually or run the following commands:

```
> REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc\OpenWithList /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc\OpenWithProgids /ve /t REG_SZ
> REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc\OpenWithProgids /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" /t REG_NONE /d 0
> REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.abc\OpenWithProgids /v abc_auto_file /t REG_NONE /d 0
```

### Refresh icon cache

The following command should refresh the Windows icon cache:

```
> %windir%\system32\ie4uinit.exe -show
```

### Assign Notepad++ to the filetype

I've noticed that - sometimes - the changes only take effect after assigning Notepad++ as the default program to open the filetype.
This is how to do that:

- Create a file with the given filetype, eg: `myFile.abc`
- Right click on the file, and select "open with" >> "another app"
- You should get a popup window like: [image]
- Select Notepad++ as the default program

### Finish

Normally the icon has changed now! And all files of that particular filetype will have the custom icon. They will open by default in Notepad++.

Perhaps you should again refresh the icon cache:

```
> %windir%\system32\ie4uinit.exe -show
```

or restart your system to let it take effect (although restarting wasn't needed for me).